# How many numbers between x and y means inclusive or exclusive generally?

Tags: terminology, convention

If someone says:

> How many numbers are a multiple of $10$ between $1$ and $100$?
>   and does not mention whether this is $[1, 100]$ or $(1, 100)$, what is the general consensus in the math world on what this exactly means?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I am unfamiliar with math and am having trouble with conventional norms in the math world.

Edit: This is in a discrete mathematics class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Between $a$ and $b$" without qualifications implies "including $a$ and $b$". This is especially true in discrete mathematics, and the sigma-notation $\sum_{k=a}^bf(k)$ is universally understood to include $k=a$ and $k=b$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!